# Order the row order according to a specific sequence in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I store some values in the mysql database and it stores the values according to this sequence. When I'm retrieving my results back this order really helped me..

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
2
3.1.1
3.1.2
4
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.3.1
```

This works perfectly until I add values like 10,11,12,13.. When adding them they are placing like this.

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.2
11
12
13
14
2
3.1.1
3.1.2
4
4.1
4.2
4.3
4.3.1
```

I need to place them according to its first numeric value in the database. Is it impossible to do like that? If so are there any other methods available to do the thing what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast the string to number, order by number and then order by string:

```
SELECT col FROM t
ORDER BY col+0, col

|   COL |
|-------|
|     1 |
|   1.1 |
| 1.1.1 |
| 1.1.2 |
|   1.2 |
| 1.2.1 |
| 1.2.2 |
|     2 |
| 3.1.1 |
| 3.1.2 |
|     4 |
|   4.1 |
|   4.2 |
|   4.3 |
| 4.3.1 |
|    10 |
|    11 |
|    12 |
|    13 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80312/1).

The solution I've provided will only sort based on the `first numeric value` of each string. The rest will be considered a string. You could parse the rest of the string values and sort based on that result but that will be very inefficient.

The correct way of fixing this is, if you are looking to sort 3 numeric values separately, then create 3 numeric columns. **Do not to use a string to sort numeric values**. That way, one value such as `'2.10'` will be come `2`, `10`, `0` and the sorting will be performed by

```
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3
```

If you want to select those three numbers separated by dots then you can use:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', col1, col2, col3) FROM t
ORDER BY col1, col2, col3
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3c26/1).

Comment: Wow... That's looking great. But Where do I need to write this query? At the point I'm sending the values to the database. This should be a feature given to the database as I suppose to do its orderings. Please give me a way where I do need to write this query. Since I'm really new to databases. Thank you very much

Comment: Oki.......... Thanks alot... I will give this a try and let you know the result... :)

Comment: :) :) Mosty It works really well. And I never thought that this could be done this much easily. Thanks alot for the help. :)

Comment: But another problem occured.. Please refer this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa31f/1

Comment: There again when 2.10 is placed it falls after 2.1 instead of placing after 2.9 .. I s there any way to correct this pattern. I think this will be a problem in other patterns as well. Ex: 2.2.10 will later fall after 2.2.1 if I'm correct.. :( :(

Comment: I've updated my answer. That will be, without any doubt, the best way to go